# Calling string.replaceAll() not working?

Tags: java

```
public class MainWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "88,24";

        if(s.contains(",")){
            s.replaceAll(",", ".");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

For the new application I'm working on I have to be able to replace a , with a . but I've had no success yet. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll(",", ".");`

Comment: `replaceAll` returns a new String. You have to use that one.

Comment: Remember, `String` are immutable, nothing can update it, even his own method don't update the instance

Comment: Your current issue aside, it looks like you are handling decimal values as strings. Don't do this. Treat them as decimals and only format the output where needed.

Comment: Just for the record: in case you feel inclined to, you can still accept answers, even on a closed question.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are **immutable**. Their content can **not** be changed upon creation.

Therefore **any** method that **changes** the content of a String object will **return** that **changed** value to the Caller. No matter if you replace, concat, ...

Therefore you need

```
s = s.replace ...
```

to have the *reference* `s` point to that **updated** string value.

Comment: I would put more than italic on "changes" ;)

Comment: Funny thing is that we have the same saying in french ;) so I get it !

Answer (score 1):

ReplaceAll is not inplace in nature.
So,you have to explicitly assign it to s.
Here is the code.

```
public class MainWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "88,24";

        if(s.contains(",")){
            s = s.replaceAll(",", ".");
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```